# Character Cartan-Killing metric

Tags: lie-algebras, characters

I am trying to identify the normal real forms of some classical semisimple Lie algebras.
These are defined as those real forms whose character $\chi:=n_+-n_-$ equals the rank of the Lie algebra. Here $n_+$ denotes the amount of positive eigenvalues of the Cartan-Killing metric $\kappa(x,y):=tr(ad_x \circ ad_y)$ and $n_-$ the amount of negative eigenvalues.

I know for example that for $A_{n-1}=sl(n,\mathbb{C})$ which has rank $n-1$, this form is $sl(n,\mathbb{R})$ but I do not see how one starts finding the eigenvalues of the Killing metric here.

My attempt was to use a basis for $sl(n,\mathbb{R})$ namely $n\times n$ real matrices $B^{i,j}(k,l)=\delta_{i,k}\delta{j,l}$ if $i \neq j$ and $H^i(1,1)=1, \; H^i(i,i)=-1$ and zero elsewhere. With this basis, you could calculate the Killing metric but diagonalising this seems tricky and a lot of work when looking at more complicated Lie algebras.

Thanks for any hints for this or for general simple Lie algebras!

Answer (score 2):

The characters $\chi:=n_{+}-n_{-}$ of real simple Lie algebras are usually given in a classification of real simple Lie algebras. I found it, for example, in Table  $7.3$ on page $295-296$ in the [this text](http://www.mat.ucm.es/%7Erutwig/Clas_ALSC.pdf).

Concerning examples computing the Killing form of a simple Lie algebra, $\kappa (x,y)$ is always a multiple of the trace form, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form). For example in the case $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb R)$ we have
$$
\kappa(X,Y)=2n \cdot{\rm tr}(XY).
$$

Comment: The table confirms my suspicion, and it's actually stated explicitly before the table in the source, that what OP calls "normal" real forms are exactly the split forms. There might be a direct proof for this without the classification. (The source also seems to have a typo and must also mean $n_+ -n_-$, not the other way around. I mean, compact forms (the other extreme) have negative definite signature, i.e. $\sigma = -dim(g)$.)