# Finding the character of real forms

Tags: lie-algebras, characters

I'm trying to find a way to find the character $\chi = n_+ - n_-$ of real forms of Lie algebras. Here $n_+$ and $n_-$ are the number of positive, negative eigenvalues of the Cartan Killing metrc respectively. For example I want to find $\chi$ for $\mathfrak{su}(p,q)$, $\mathfrak{su}^*(2n)$, $\mathfrak{so}^*(2n)$ and the like. My first idea was to look for the maximal compact subalgebra which would then give $n_-$ since this is the unique one where $n_+ = 0$. Hence, if we know the dimension of the maximal compact subalgebra, we get $n_-$.

But I'm stuck here. How do I find $n_+$? And how do I even find the maximal compact subalgebra for a given Lie algebra and its dimension?

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ I also noticed that if we have the dimension of the real form, then we necessarily have $n_+$ too, since $n = n_+ + n_-$. So my question boils down to 1) How do I find the maximal compact subalgebras? 2) How can I easily know the dimensions?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4357013/96384.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Great! must've looked over that one. It seems like the solution to your linked question is to just 'look at the tables'. I'm wondering how you can find this from scratch?

Comment: @Geigercounter "from scratch" is just finding an orthogonal basis and counting the positive and negative parts. In several cases it is not to hard to think of such a basis but you can always use Gram-Schmidt to build one as well. Note also that for simple Lie algebras all invariant bilinear forms are scales of the Killing form so you can take the standard representation and compute $\mathrm{tr}(XY)$ rather than $\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{ad}_X\mathrm{ad}_Y)$ to get the same signature.